# nodeMCU TLS certificate error

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, esp8266, nodemcu

I am building realy simple IoT project, and I am stuck on nodeMCU TLS problem. I have MQTT broker on my Raspberry pi, all certificates are correctly inserted (everything working fine with Paho Client on same raspberry or with Mqtt.fx client on remote PC), but when I try to connect from my ESP8266 with nodeMCU I am getting SSL handshake error (yes, I am using same cert file for all mentioned clients). My ESP8266 code looks like this:

```
    tls.cert.verify([[
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    ]])

    m:connect(config.HOST, 8883, 1, function(con) 
        print("Connected to MQTT broker")    
        register_myself()
        -- And then pings each 1000 milliseconds
        tmr.stop(6)
        tmr.alarm(6, 1000, 1, send_ping)
    end, handle_mqtt_error)
```

I am getting error code **-5 (mqtt.CONN_FAIL_SERVER_NOT_FOUND)** from m:connect, but when I analyze packets using Wireshark it TLS handshake looks like this:

> - Client Hello
> - Server Hello
> - Certificate, Server Hello Done
> - TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)

Also in ESPlorer console there is this line: **E:M 544**, I dont realy know what that means.

Comment: Create a new custom firmware and turn debug "logging" on (over serial). With near certainty you'll see an error code from the mbedTLS library which you then can look up at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/mbedtls/ssl.h#L62.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have tried that and got an "handshake failure" message with an error code 0x2700... I am bit confused, because it is not in docs (or atleast I cant see it)

Comment: Are you aware of the constraints wrt cipher suites documented at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/tls/? Could it be that your cert uses an unsupported/disabled cipher suite which you'd first need to configure in https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_mbedtls.h? Did you query https://tls.mbed.org/discussions for that error code?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone encountres same thing, my problem was actualy caused by high memory usage in other parts of my project, I used AES for encryption on application layer, without it everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266 is too slow to use certificates reliably. You should upgrade to the ESP32 or something with a little more support for it.

See section 3.2 of this below PDF, referencing SSL handshake failure for ESP8266. This looks similar to your issue. You really have to get creative and lean to make it work reliably, which lowers the value of whatever you are making. So, it might not be worth the hassle.

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/5a-esp8266_sdk_ssl_user_manual_en.pdf

Also, try TLS 1.1 to see what it does. It might not support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Are you sure, thats the problem here? I mean, it is not like, there are some good handshakes and some bad. Even ESP memory looks good all the time.

Comment: Updated answer with pdf reference.

Comment: Its the same problem for each version :)

Comment: "section 3.2 of this below PDF" - this describes the use case of running a TLS _server_ on the device.