# Troubles verifying MQTT broker with TLS

Tags: ssl, mqtt, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using nodemcu on the ESP8266 to connect to an MQTT broker and want to use TLS. I am testing using test.mosquitto.org. I have found that I can connect to it using TLS, but it fails to connect when I have it verify the broker with the certificate provided. I get error code -5 which is mqtt.CONN_FAIL_SERVER_NOT_FOUND. I have found the verification works in Python/Paho using the same certificate. Am I doing something wrong?

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 11592951b90707cdcb6d751876170bf4da82850d
    SSL: true
    modules: crypto,file,gpio,mqtt,net,node,rtcfifo,rtcmem,rtctime,sjson,tmr,uart,wifi,tls
 build created on 2019-01-23 05:04
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(6ab97e9)
lua: cannot open init.lua
>
>
> =tls.cert.verify([[-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>> MIIC8DCCAlmgAwIBAgIJAOD63PlXjJi8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGQMQswCQYD
>> VQQGEwJHQjEXMBUGA1UECAwOVW5pdGVkIEtpbmdkb20xDjAMBgNVBAcMBURlcmJ5
>> MRIwEAYDVQQKDAlNb3NxdWl0dG8xCzAJBgNVBAsMAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQDDA1tb3Nx
>> dWl0dG8ub3JnMR8wHQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhByb2dlckBhdGNob28ub3JnMB4XDTEy
>> MDYyOTIyMTE1OVoXDTIyMDYyNzIyMTE1OVowgZAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRcwFQYD
>> VQQIDA5Vbml0ZWQgS2luZ2RvbTEOMAwGA1UEBwwFRGVyYnkxEjAQBgNVBAoMCU1v
>> c3F1aXR0bzELMAkGA1UECwwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAMMDW1vc3F1aXR0by5vcmcxHzAd
>> BgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEHJvZ2VyQGF0Y2hvby5vcmcwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
>> gY0AMIGJAoGBAMYkLmX7SqOT/jJCZoQ1NWdCrr/pq47m3xxyXcI+FLEmwbE3R9vM
>> rE6sRbP2S89pfrCt7iuITXPKycpUcIU0mtcT1OqxGBV2lb6RaOT2gC5pxyGaFJ+h
>> A+GIbdYKO3JprPxSBoRponZJvDGEZuM3N7p3S/lRoi7G5wG5mvUmaE5RAgMBAAGj
>> UDBOMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTad2QneVztIPQzRRGj6ZHKqJTv5jAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTa
>> d2QneVztIPQzRRGj6ZHKqJTv5jAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUA
>> A4GBAAqw1rK4NlRUCUBLhEFUQasjP7xfFqlVbE2cRy0Rs4o3KS0JwzQVBwG85xge
>> REyPOFdGdhBY2P1FNRy0MDr6xr+D2ZOwxs63dG1nnAnWZg7qwoLgpZ4fESPD3PkA
>> 1ZgKJc2zbSQ9fCPxt2W3mdVav66c6fsb7els2W2Iz7gERJSX
>> -----END CERTIFICATE-----]])
true
> 
> 
> =tls.cert.verify(true)
true
> sntp.sync('pool.ntp.org',
>>   function(sec, usec, server)
>>     print("Clock Synced: "..sec..", "..usec..", "..server)
>>     end,
>>   function(error_code)
>>     print("Clock Sync Failed: "..sntp_connect_status_codes[error_code])
>>   end
>> )
> Clock Synced: 1548219962, 492942, 12.167.151.1

> MQTTClient = mqtt.Client("clientid", 120)
> 
> MQTTClient:connect("test.mosquitto.org", 8883, 1, function(c) print("connected") end, function (client, reason) print("error", reason) end)
> error -5
```

Comment: You might want to turn debug on in your firmware then see if any debug messages help narrow the issue down

Comment: Also, make sure you're programming against the latest `dev` firmware. There were some TLS improvements/fixes recently.

Comment: Your problem/symptoms look similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357327/nodemcu-tls-certificate-error

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into those things.